# Using Thread.new in Rails action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parallel-processing

When using a multi-process app server and running `Thread.new` (spawning multiple threads) in a controller action, is parallelism attained? Or does the GIL prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) prevents more than one Ruby thread from running at any given time, which has the net effect of restricting Ruby to one core only. Other than that, they are actual threads.

If you need true concurrency you need to run a Ruby without a GIL, like JRuby.

That being said, threads in Ruby are fine for many operations where you're not pinning a CPU core. If you are you should probably create background jobs for those operations through [ActiveJob](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/active_job_basics.html). These can run in one or more processes on different systems if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

The answer of @tadman is perfectly correct, I just want to expand a little bit on the 3 paragraph.

When are threads a good thing to use in MRI Ruby? Mostly, if you are bound by IO operations. So, if you have a Rails action where you have many Database queries and/or http requests you may make those in a Thread, safe the request in a Thread local variable, join them together and then handle the thread local variables. This way you will achieve a noticeable performance improvement.

This can look like this:

```
threads << Thread.new do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
  t = Thread.current
  t[:variable_name] = Model.find_by(col: data)
  end
end
joined_threads = threads.map &:join
joined_threads.each do |t|
  t.keys.each do |key|
    k = key.to_s.downcase
    next if k.start_with?("active") || k.start_with?("__")
    instance_variable_set "@#{key}", t[key]
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the details! I'm not understanding how that gets around the fact that the GIL will prevent one thread from running at the same time?

Comment: @mstrom Sorry that I didn't answer earlier. I wrote a Blog post that will explain your question as well. Here is a link: 
https://link.medium.com/RCMyp9fiiX

Comment: Is with_connection needed, given "Rails automatically wraps web requests and Active Job workers"?https://guides.rubyonrails.org/threading_and_code_execution.html#reloader